# Best way to store data for multiple category?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I don’t know if it’s the best way but right now, I use sqflite, but I can store data for only one of the categories. How can do something like, when I add an animal, I will choose one of them from a DropdownMenuItem, then if I choose Dog it will store the data in the Dog menu only.

The only tutorials I find online is for notepad (one category) store only. If someone could explain to me or like a tutorial which can help, I would be so thankful.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXgr6.png)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I don’t have a code really, it’s a general question to find out how to store data for categories.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I want to use sqflite, but I don’t understand how to use if I have like 30 categories. Should I make 30 different db for them? The only tutorial I find is store only one kind of thig a note. But for example, if I want to make a to do note app where I can choose between days of the week what I want. Then what should I do?

If you don’t understand let me know I will try to rephrase.

Comment: you need 1 table to store your animal and display it on gridview, then another table for data with a column that tag what kind of animal is your data or row so that you can easily query it in WHERE clause.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use normalized schema with manyToMany joining table:
- you have `animals(id,name)`
- you have `categories(id,name)`
- create `animal_categories(animal_id,category_id)` -> each row joins 1 animal and 1 category -> add multiple rows to allow animal have more categories.

You have to store Animal first to have its id and then insert rows for the connection with multiple categories.